# Why can't I remove the %20 from a URL evaluated by a contextual filter?

Tags: views

I created a view with contextual filters with taxonomy terms that have two words, so that space creates a %20 on the URL. I found out that the solution is to checked the "Transform spaces to dashes in URL" box, but that still doesn't get rid of the URL. Does anybody here know why? I'm attaching screen shots of the configuration of the view and of the URL pattern that I set with the pathauto module. Thanks!
[image: drupal view]

[image: drupal view]

[image: drupal view]

[image: drupal image]

[image: drupal view]